# Using a dynamic formula with parrallel kringing in R

Tags: r, loop, kriging, parallel-processing, parallel

I am trying to achieve parallel Kriging in R on several variables using a loop. Here is a reproducible example using data meuse and a code for parallel kriging that I found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237672/how-to-achieve-parallel-kriging-in-r-to-speed-up-the-process). In the code below, each kriging is overwritten, but that's not the issue, since I can't even run the first kriging.

```
library(parallel)
library(sp)
library(gstat)
data(meuse)
    names <- colnames(meuse)[3:6]
    coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
    data(meuse.grid)
    gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
    m <- vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04)
    no_cores <- 7
    # ordinary kriging:
    for (i in 1:length(names)) {
      parts <- split(x = 1:length(meuse.grid), f = 1:no_cores)
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)          
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c("meuse", "meuse.grid", "m", "parts"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
          clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, expr = c(library('sp'), library('gstat')))
          parallelX <- parLapply(cl = cl, X = 1:no_cores, fun = function(x) krige(formula = log(get(names[i]))~1, locations = meuse, newdata = meuse.grid[parts[[x]],], model = m))
          stopCluster(cl)
          # Merge all the predictions    
          mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(parallelX[[1]], parallelX[[2]])
          mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[3]])
          mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[4]])
          mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[5]])
          mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[6]])
          mergeParallelX <- maptools::spRbind(mergeParallelX, parallelX[[7]])
          # Create SpatialPixelsDataFrame from mergeParallelX
          mergeParallelX <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = mergeParallelX, data = mergeParallelX@data)
        }
```

I keep having issues which are, I think, related to the dynamic formula. I tried a lot of other functions, such as `paste`, `paste0`, `as.formula`, `objects`, etc. Nothing works, I can't paste the variable names into looped parallel kriging, no matter how I code the dynamic formula. Maybe that's because of how the parallel function is coded?

Any idea about a dynamic formula that works with the above code?

Comment: What does "not working" mean here? Is this really only a Q about how to dynamically construct a formula?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the vocabulary I had to use for this issue. So, the answer is yes and no, apparently a formula constructed dynamically don't work with the package parallel. For example the structure you gave below doesn't work. I will edit the question and the title to reflect on this issue.

Comment: As written you are trying to do `n_cores` replications of kriging of each of the columns? Because your loop over the columns is outside the cluster creation and execution. This seems a bit off. Normally you'd throw all the replicated work inside the cluster and let the cluster's `n_cores` specification optimise the number of cores working. That then puts `i` in side the cluster loop. Also as written you're only going to return the value from the last column's kriging.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have a double loop to record all kringing, and I use detectCores for setting the number of clusters. I wrote the code this way in the Q to have a simple and reproducible example. What doesn't work is the dynamic formula here, but if you have a suggestion for a better structure I am ears. That's the first time I try parallel computing so I am quite a newbie here.

Comment: And yes, since Kriging predictions are independent of each other, I am just trying to speed up the processing time by making all my cores work at the same time for each variable successively, rather than allocating different variables to different cores.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that your problem is constructing a formula dynamically, you can build one as character and convert to a formula with `as.formula`:

So this:

```
> k1 = krige(log(copper)~1, meuse, meuse.grid, model = m)
[using ordinary kriging]
```

is the same as:

```
> k2 = krige(as.formula("log(copper)~1"), meuse, meuse.grid, model = m)
[using ordinary kriging]
```

which you can construct

```
> names
[1] "cadmium" "copper"  "lead"    "zinc"   
> i
[1] 2
> k3 = krige(as.formula(paste0("log(",names[i],")~1")), meuse, meuse.grid, model = m)
[using ordinary kriging]
```

And then:

```
> identical(k1, k2)
[1] TRUE
> identical(k1, k3)
[1] TRUE
> identical(k2, k3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I just edited the question/title. as.formula(paste0("log(",names[i],")~1")) doesn't work either with the package parallel